# Null ImageView Array

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, imageview

I am a little confused at the moment I am trying to `setImageResource` to some Images in an ImageView Array. I replicated the error in a simpler project so here is the code. I am sure this must be a silly mistake but I have tried a lot and could not figure out the proper execution.  I can't understand why images is a null object reference since I already initialised it in every way I could think of. I am getting this error in the line mentioned in the code.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object reference.

package com.example.test;

import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ImageView image1;
private ImageView image2;
private ImageView image3;
private ImageView image;
private ImageView[] images = {image1, image2, image3, image};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image1 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    setImages();

}

public void setImages() {
    //This is where I am getting the error
    images[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
    images[1].setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
    images[2].setImageResource(R.drawable.c);
    images[3].setImageResource(R.drawable.d);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `images` array after getting their values in the `onCreate` method because `image1`, `image2`, `image3`, and `image` were `null` at the time of the initialization of images due to the fact that initializers (the one you used for images) are executed before constructors (and definitely before the `onCreate()` method).  Try the following instead,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView image1;
    private ImageView image2;
    private ImageView image3;
    private ImageView image;
    private ImageView[] images;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        image1 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
        image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        images = new ImageView[4];

        images[0] = image1;
        image[1] = image2;
        image[2] = image3;
        image[3] = image;

        setImages();

    }

    public void setImages() {
        images[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
        images[1].setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
        images[2].setImageResource(R.drawable.c);
        images[3].setImageResource(R.drawable.d);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried that android studio complains and says Array initializer is not allowed here on line `images = {image1, image2, image3, image};`

Comment: I have edited the answer

Comment: great it works. Only thing I want to point out is that on your eddited answer images are not an array of int but ImageView in line `images =new int[4];. Change that and it will be correct. Thanks

Comment: yeah I have corrected it, and you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView[] images = new ImageView[4];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

images [0]=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
images [1] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
images [2] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);
images [3] = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

setImages();

}

public void setImages() {
//This is where I am getting the error
images[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.a);
images[1].setImageResource(R.drawable.b);
images[2].setImageResource(R.drawable.c);
images[3].setImageResource(R.drawable.d);
}
```

Comment: This is cleaner than all the other answers. Thank you and all the others that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

When you have created array of images like below

```
 private ImageView[] images;
```

before creation of image1, image2 like on It will always return a null.

Try to use below code.

```
private ImageView[] images = {image1, image2, image3, image};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image1 =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
    image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
    image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
   images = new ImageView[]{image1, image2, image3, image};
    setImages();

}
```

Hope these help you.

Comment: I tried that android studio complains and says Array initializer is not allowed here on line `images = {image1, image2, image3, image};`

Comment: use these images = new ImageView[]{image1, image2, image3, image};